# test RDP credentials user and password from command line without gui

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have been searching for the whole day about the idea of checking windows RDP credentials user and password

I found FreeRDP which can be check user and password from RDP IP

after few research I found this command

```
xfreerdp --ignore-certificate --authonly -u user -p pass host
```

when I tried it I received this error

> [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Please check that the $DISPLAY environment variable is properly set.

then Id know that it must be compiled so to not ask for x-server I had found this [tutorial](http://opentechnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/compile-headless-freerdp-credential-checking.html) and all goes successfully in 'make' steps and building but when tried to test in the final it didn't work I used this command

```
./client/X11/xfreerdp /cert-ignore +auth-only /v:10.0.2.2:4242 /u:testuser /d:Spoon /p:pass
```

i got error that the

> -bash: ./client/X11/xfreerdp: No such file or directory

and I am sure that I am in the right path i think that's because tutorial is too old and need too updates

I am using ubuntu 20 and digital ocean VPS

can any one help me I want just to make a command that check RDP user and password if it good return good and I will make an PHP file to execute this command so i can access it easily

Comment: Oh, yes, got stuck with this one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here. Solved with Xvfb, a fake X server
in ubuntu

```
apt install xvfb
```

launch it, ie, with

```
Xvfb :99 & export DISPLAY=:99
```

And now, xfreerdp command will run without issues.